# stepwise time series pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following problem in pandas where I have a time series with specific time stamps and values:

```
 ts1 = DatetimeIndex(['1995-05-26', '1995-05-30', '1995-05-31', '1995-06-01', 
                      '1995-06-02', '1995-06-05', '1995-06-06', '1995-06-08',
                      '1995-06-09', '1995-06-12'],
                     dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None, tz=None)
```

Then I have a time index that contains these timestamps, and some other timestamps in between. How do I create a stepwise function (forward fill) that fills forward the same constant value from [T-1, T) for T in ts1?

Comment: Why doesn't `.ffill()` work in this case? Where are the values?

Comment: How would it work exactly? There's no documentation in the pandas index.

Comment: What does your DataFrame of Series look like?  You've just provided an index with no data.

Comment: ` ts2=pd.date_range('01-Jan-1996', '01-Jan-1997', freq='1BM')`
then `ts3 = pd.date_range('01-Jan-1996', '01-Jan-1997', freq='1BD')`
and `df3 = pd.DataFrame(range(len(ts2), index=ts2)` .So how do I create a stepwise-dataframe df4, where for each date T in ts3 the value between [T,T-1) for df4 is df3[T].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
dfg1 = pd.DataFrame(range(len(ts1)), index=ts1)
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=min(ts1), end=max(ts1), freq='D')
>>> dfg1.reindex(index=idx).ffill()

            0
1995-05-26  0
1995-05-27  0
1995-05-28  0
1995-05-29  0
1995-05-30  1
1995-05-31  2
1995-06-01  3
1995-06-02  4
1995-06-03  4
1995-06-04  4
1995-06-05  5
1995-06-06  6
1995-06-07  6
1995-06-08  7
1995-06-09  8
1995-06-10  8
1995-06-11  8
1995-06-12  9
```